# How to reuse docker-compose projects?

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

I have defined a base configuration for a web server using docker-compose, consisting of

- `db`: Based on the MySQL image, with some custom schemas and data being loaded upon startup.
- `tomcat`: Based on the Tomcat image, deploying a web application (exploded WAR file) into Tomcat when the server starts up.

The web app connects to the `db` container for data persistence. Both are wired together through docker-compose, so I can `docker-compose up -d` to start both servers. This works great. I have stored the docker-compose configuration, the MySQL data files (SQL) and the web application artifacts in a Git repo, which other people can clone for easy local setup.

Now I want to use this basic configuration as a starting point for multiple other projects: For each project, I want to use the base project, and then build on top of that. I can easily extend the docker-compose files using the `extends` feature, but before I can do that, I need to figure out how to reuse the whole project without having to duplicate it.

In each of the projects, I need the full "base" project including all of the Docker stuff, the SQL files and the web application, and then I'll add things to it here and there, like different configurations, additional web applications, etc.

What's the standard way to do this? A couple of things I've thought about:

- Using Git's `submodule` feature, I would create a "base" submodule in each project and use the base functionality from there. Downside: clunky usability of `git submodule` (initialization, updates).
- Using Git's `subtree` feature, I would create a "base" directory as a Git subtree in each project. Easier to use than `submodule`, but replicates the whole "base" project (which will be huge) to each new project.

Did I miss any other options? How to address these requirements without sacrificing reuse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I didn't receive an answer here, I gave the `git submodule` approach a try:

In the project where I want to reuse the "base" Docker configuration, I created the submodule:

```
git submodule add https://my.githost/git/projects/base-docker.git base
```

This cloned the "base" project into the local `base` folder, which I then committed and pushed to the server. Other people can now use this - I added documentation to show how to clone/update the project:

```
# Clone the project
git clone https://my.githost/git/projects/consumer-docker.git

# CD into the project directory
cd consumer-docker

# Init the submodule to download the dependencies
git submodule update --init
```

When there are changes in the "base" project, I can simply run

```
git submodule update --remote --merge
```

to update the submodule to the latest `master` and then commit/push these changes.

In the project that is reusing the "base" project, I can reference the base project's services in the `docker-compose.yaml` file like this:

```
database:
  extends:
    file: base/database.yaml
    service: database
```

So far this is working rather well, it avoids duplicating configuration across projects, and allows me to reuse functionality pretty much 100%.

Comment: Please keep in mind: the keyword `extends` is supported up to version 2.1 of compose. And it's not recommended in version 3.x, which I don't agree much. -_-!